# How to write a csv file line by line?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a website and I have collected 3 different type of information from the website. I have thousands of records in the 3 list but for simplicity, I am adding a few records.

```
List1 = ['DealerName']
List2 = ['Person1','Person2']
List3 = ['crisp nori, hot rice, and cold fish','takeout,fancy presentation, piled']
```

I have to write an output **csv file line by line** with 3 columns(List1, List2, List3) and the list information for the 3 columns. The 'DealerName' is constant for all records. I am facing trouble because there are commas in List3 which is separating the information in individual columns(different cells). The desired output file should look like this

[image: List item]

Thanks for the comments. Based on one of the comments, I made some modifications in the code and tried using the following code but it's not giving me the desired output.

```
List1 = ['DealerName']
List2 = ['Person1','Person2']
List3 = ['crisp nori, hot rice, and cold fish','takeout,fancy presentation, piled']

Output_File = open("Output.csv", "w")
Output_File.write("List1,List2,List3")

import csv, itertools
rows = itertools.zip_longest([List1, List2, List3])
c = csv.writer(Output_File)
c.writerows(rows)

Output_File.close()
```

Comment: Take a look at the CSV modules [https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). You need to wrap each item in quotes, but the CSV module will take care of doing this for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case (in other words, not in the most general sense), specifying the first element of `List1` as the `fillvalue` argument when calling `itertools.zip_longest()` looks like it would make it work:

```
import csv, itertools

List1 = ['DealerName']
List2 = ['Person1','Person2']
List3 = ['crisp nori, hot rice, and cold fish', 'takeout,fancy presentation, piled']

with open("Output.csv", "w", newline="") as Output_File:
    Output_File.write("List1,List2,List3\n")
    writer = csv.writer(Output_File)
    rows = itertools.zip_longest(List1, List2, List3, fillvalue=List1[0])
    writer.writerows(rows)
```

Contents of `output.csv` file afterward:

```
List1,List2,List3
DealerName,Person1,"crisp nori, hot rice, and cold fish"
DealerName,Person2,"takeout,fancy presentation, piled"
```

Answer (score 3):

Use csv:

```
import csv, itertools
rows = itertools.zip_longest(List1, List2, List3)
csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

The csv module will automatically wrap strings containing comma in a quote, which will read fine.

**Edit:**

You can loop over the rows and output them with [writerow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) instead of writerows, and that would fulfill your requirement of doing this line by line.

**Edit 2:**
I've fixed my answer. `itertools.zip_longest([List1, List2, List3])` should be `itertools.zip_longest(List1, List2, List3)`

Also you're going to want a newline after your header so `Output_File.write("List1,List2,List3\n")` instead of `Output_File.write("List1,List2,List3")`

Comment: I just had to copy Rocky Li's wording for kick's and giggle's, since it works for this answer to. You can use either Pandas or CSV. CSV is built-in to Python, and is easier to learn. Pandas is meant for working with datasets, and has a lot of additional functionality surrounding it.

Comment: Hey, I tried with this code but it's throwing some error. As you described, I tried modifying a few lines but it's not giving me the desired result. I have edited the post based on your code.

Answer (score 2):

Use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([List1, List2, List3]).T 
df.to_csv('your.csv', index=False)
```

Pandas will automatically wrap strings containing comma in a quote, which will read fine.

Comment: Agree this is good, but does not seem to have the stated constraint of `line by line`

Comment: I understand that it's quite straightforward with a data frame using pandas but it's a requirement that I have to write the output line by line using file commands. Thanks for your answer though.